# Tasks being called synchronously despite being declared async

Tags: c#, multithreading

Consider the following code:

```
public async static Task<bool> Sleeper(int sleepTime)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sleeping for " + sleepTime + " seconds");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * sleepTime);
    return true;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    List<Task<bool>> tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();

    Console.WriteLine("Kicking off tasks");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Sleeper(rnd.Next(10, 15)));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("All tasks launched");

    Task.WhenAll(tasks);


    int nComplete = 0;
    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        if (task.Result)
            nComplete++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(nComplete + " Successful tasks");


}
```

Each task should sleep for a random amount of time (between 10-15 seconds).  However my output looks like the following

```
Kicking off tasks
Sleeping for 12 seconds
Sleeping for 14 seconds
Sleeping for 12 seconds
All tasks launched
3 Successful tasks
```

Each "task" clearly waited for the previous task to be completed before starting (I also saw this when debugging and stepping through the code), why is this?

**EDIT** A lot of people have mentioned using `Task.Delay` which does work as expected.  But what if I'm not doing anything like sleeping, just a lot of work.  Consider a large do nothing loop

```
int s = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000000000; i++)
      s *= i;
```

This still executes synchronously

Comment: Pro tip: `async` doesn't make your method run asynchronously, `await` does.

Comment: Your method produces a compiler warning telling you that the code will run synchronously, and explaining why.  All you needed to do was *read the warning that the method generates*.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` should be a compiler warning in async methods. I even make that mistake once in awhile.

Comment: To clarify juharr's comment above:  **async turns on the ability to use await**, which allows you to *call asynchronous methods almost as though they were synchronous*. Async does **not** create asynchrony where none existed before.  It lets you write an *already asynchronous* method as though you were writing a synchronous method, by identifying the points at which the high-latency operation begins. `await` identifies those points.  You put a thread to sleep, *the thread goes to sleep*. If the method is not already asynchronous `async` does not make it asynchronous.

Comment: @JonathanAllen: Thread.Sleep should be a compiler warning, period. It's almost never the right thing to do outside of test code.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is being down-voted. It is clearly written and I'm sure it a common mistake when first learning how to use async.

Answer (score 1):

`async` does not mean "runs on another thread". Stephen Toub's blog goes into a lot more detail, but under the hood the current SynchronizationContext and the operations performed determines if and when a task runs on a separate thread. In your case, Thread.Sleep doesn't do anything explicitly to run on a different thread, so it doesn't.

If you used `await Task.Delay(1000 + sleepTime)` instead of `Thread.Sleep` I think you'll find that things work as you expect, because `Task.Delay` is plugged into the async/await infrastructure, while `Thread.Sleep` isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using `Thread.Sleep` which is sleeping the thread which invokes `Sleeper`. `async` methods start on the thread which call them hence you are sleeping your main application thread.

In asynchronous code, you should be using `Task.Delay` like so:

```
public async static Task<bool> Sleeper(int sleepTime)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sleeping for " + sleepTime + " seconds");
    await Task.Delay(1000 * sleepTime).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: To slightly modify my question, what if I wasn't using a sleep function at all, but a large do-nothing loop (i.e. count all numbers from 0-1000000000).  This still executes synchronously, how can I call that function asyncly

Comment: Use `Task.Run` for something which is CPU intensive.

Comment: Is there a way to give `Task.Run` a timeout?  i.e i'm doing something cpu intensive but i want that thread killed if it takes longer than 10 minutes

Comment: Create a `CancellationTokenSource` with a timeout (use [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139115(v=vs.110).aspx)) and pass the `.Token` to the [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh160373(v=vs.110).aspx) then inside the callback you can call `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`

Answer (score 0):

`async` does not mean "run on another thread". I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that goes into detail about what `async` *does* mean.

In fact, `Sleeper` will generate a compiler warning informing you of the fact that it will run *synchronously*. It's a good idea to turn on "Warnings as Errors" for all new projects.

If you have CPU-bound work to do, you may run it on a thread pool thread and asynchronously wait for it to complete by using `await Task.Run`, as such:

```
public static bool Sleeper(int sleepTime);

...

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  var sleepTime = rnd.Next(10, 15);
  tasks.Add(Task.run(() => Sleeper(sleepTime)));
}
```